# Responsive Inline SVG using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg, responsive

How to make an inline svg icon responsive using Bootstrap? Here is a sample code:

```
<svg id="mute-audio" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewbox="-10 -10 68 68">
    <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="34">
        <title>Mute Audio</title>
    </circle>
    <path class="on" transform="scale(0.6), translate(17,18)" d="M38 22h-3.4c0 1.49-.31 2.87-.87 4.1l2.46 2.46C37.33 26.61 38 24.38 38 22zm-8.03.33c0-.11.03-.22.03-.33V10c0-3.32-2.69-6-6-6s-6 2.68-6 6v.37l11.97 11.96zM8.55 6L6 8.55l12.02 12.02v1.44c0 3.31 2.67 6 5.98 6 .45 0 .88-.06 1.3-.15l3.32 3.32c-1.43.66-3 1.03-4.62 1.03-5.52 0-10.6-4.2-10.6-10.2H10c0 6.83 5.44 12.47 12 13.44V42h4v-6.56c1.81-.27 3.53-.9 5.08-1.81L39.45 42 42 39.46 8.55 6z" fill="white"/>

    <path class="off" transform="scale(0.6), translate(17,18)"  d="M24 28c3.31 0 5.98-2.69 5.98-6L30 10c0-3.32-2.68-6-6-6-3.31 0-6 2.68-6 6v12c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6zm10.6-6c0 6-5.07 10.2-10.6 10.2-5.52 0-10.6-4.2-10.6-10.2H10c0 6.83 5.44 12.47 12 13.44V42h4v-6.56c6.56-.97 12-6.61 12-13.44h-3.4z"  fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

I tried different:

1. class="img-responsive" in svg
2. class="embed-responsive-item" in
   the container div

No luck so far. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`viewbox` should be `viewBox`. SVG attributes are case sensitive.

You also need to remove the `width` and `height` values - or change them to `"100%"`.

```html
<svg id="mute-audio" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 68 68">
    <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="34">
        <title>Mute Audio</title>
    </circle>
    <path class="on" transform="scale(0.6), translate(17,18)" d="M38 22h-3.4c0 1.49-.31 2.87-.87 4.1l2.46 2.46C37.33 26.61 38 24.38 38 22zm-8.03.33c0-.11.03-.22.03-.33V10c0-3.32-2.69-6-6-6s-6 2.68-6 6v.37l11.97 11.96zM8.55 6L6 8.55l12.02 12.02v1.44c0 3.31 2.67 6 5.98 6 .45 0 .88-.06 1.3-.15l3.32 3.32c-1.43.66-3 1.03-4.62 1.03-5.52 0-10.6-4.2-10.6-10.2H10c0 6.83 5.44 12.47 12 13.44V42h4v-6.56c1.81-.27 3.53-.9 5.08-1.81L39.45 42 42 39.46 8.55 6z" fill="white"/>

    <path class="off" transform="scale(0.6), translate(17,18)"  d="M24 28c3.31 0 5.98-2.69 5.98-6L30 10c0-3.32-2.68-6-6-6-3.31 0-6 2.68-6 6v12c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6zm10.6-6c0 6-5.07 10.2-10.6 10.2-5.52 0-10.6-4.2-10.6-10.2H10c0 6.83 5.44 12.47 12 13.44V42h4v-6.56c6.56-.97 12-6.61 12-13.44h-3.4z"  fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: then why VSCODE tells me everything should be lowercase?

Comment: If it is saying that, it is wrong.  Maybe SVG elements weren't considered when the HTML validation was implemented.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I change to 100% and it works!